# Isekai in reverse

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I'm looking for a fantasy manga where a guy is sent back to Earth but retains his abilities. Only to find out that a few of his classmates have abilities of their own. Even becomes phone friends with one of the girls in his class.

Comment: This is quite brief could you [edit] to add anything else you remember?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is [The Hero Who Returned Remains the Strongest in the Modern World](https://mangadex.org/title/35794/the-hero-who-returned-remains-the-strongest-in-the-modern-world).

The story is about a guy who returned to earth with his abilities. He finds out one of his classmates is a shrine maiden who hunts demons.  He becomes phone friends with her. His class also gained a transfer student who is a demon hunter from the Vatican.

Comment: Available as both a manga and in text form. :-P I got caught up in reading it, so you beat me to posting it.